Share Canvas App with SharePoint connector to users without license
I'm working on a Microsoft Canvas App with only a standard connector to SharePoint.
The canvas app can read and write the list.
When I hover over the details, the app show the required licenses: An app that only uses standard connectors. An end user must have Power Apps included with Office 365 plan, Per App Plan, or a Per User Plan to access this app.
I want to share the app with user who do not have any license.
I read there is the power apps player app for iPhone and Windows.
Is it possible to share the app for users without any license?

User will need Office 365 plan license which includes access to SharePoint and Power Apps. So, I don't think you can share the app for users without any license.

No, it is not possible to share a canvas app with users who do not have any license. An end user must have Power Apps included with Office 365 plan, Per App Plan, or a Per User Plan to access an app that only uses standard connectors.
